# What is the best practice to keep odoo under git version control

Tags: git, odoo-10

We have an odoo installation on our company server.

This is the backend of our website which is being run by odoo.

Also we have some other custom modules rather than the website that are being offered to customers as a service.

I want to put the source code in a git repository to achieve the following:

We need a way to backup our data existing on server.

Provide a means to revert back to a previous safe point if things went wrong.

work locally on everyone's machine instead of the server while be able to synchronize changes to the server.

separate the testing environment from the development environment.

I have already done the following: the original odoo installation and the custom addons folder were put in a git repo and were pushed to the remote repo, no problem with that.

But when I cloned the repository on another machine, off course the odoo installation didn't work because the original installation was made for another user on another machine and with dependencies stored on the original machine

So I was thinking to put the custom addons folder only under git while keeping the odoo installation outside the repository.

but this will give arise to another problem: the website customization made from the website builder will not be reflected on other machines, am I right?

So please advice what is the best practice to use git in a case similar to mine.